# Why are my results different when using a literal string versus a local variable

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following loop.

```
for (var key in criteria) {

    var exists = Object.keys(item).some(function(k) {
        return item[k] === "Test";
    })
}
```

This works perfectly. And I get a 15 `trues` based on the number of items. However if I change it to the following:

```
for (var key in criteria) {

    var myString = item[key];

    var exists = Object.keys(item).some(function(k) {
        return item[k] === myString;
    });
}
```

Where I know the `item[key]` will equate to "Test" at some point in my loop, it does not produce the same result. In fact it returns all `trues`,

Criteria is an object that is like this:

```
{
  habitat_type: "Mangroves", 
  issue_specific_terms: "Test"
}
```

Item is also an object like:

```
{
  habitat_type: "Streams and rivers", 
  cci: "Low productivity/loss of agriculture", 
  intervention_type: "Restoration", 
  issue_specific_terms: "Test", 
  country: "United States of America"
}
```

Comment: Hi @user142553, please complete your post by adding further details. More specifically, please include the source data (the `criteria` and the `item` objects) and the explicit question ("Why are my results different when using a literal string versus a local variable?").

Comment: Can you maybe provide a fiddle of what you are seeing?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do here. Can you explain (in words) what this code is trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change what `myString` is - currently, it's always going to be equal because `criteria` doesn't come into it currently. Change `myString` to `criteria[key]`:

```
for (var key in criteria) {

    var myString = criteria[key];

    var exists = Object.keys(item).some(k => item[k] === myString);

}
```